# Discord.py suggestion command

Tags: discord.py

I hae looked everywhere and haven't found the answer. I'm pretty new to discord.py. I want to make a /suggestion command and whatever comes after it gets stored into a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is something that you are looking for?

```py
@bot.command()
async def suggest(msg,*,user_suggestion):
    file=open(r"E:\Test12\Testing\hello.json",'r')
    data=json.load(file)
    data.append(user_suggestion)
    with open(r"E:\Test12\Testing\hello.json",'w')as f:
        f.write(str(json.dumps(data)))
        f.close()
    await msg.message.add_reaction(emoji='\U00002705')
```

Comment: Thanks but hpw would you get json so it could get stored into it?

Comment: Isn't what I showed a JSON data format being stored in JSON file?

Comment: Oh, Okay! Thanks!